# Redirect to home page after form processing with Elementor Forms API (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, elementor

I have a multi step form built with Elementor in my Wordpress application. I am using the Elementor Forms API in PHP to grab data submitted by the form and create a custom post within Wordpress (5.7.1). Once the form has been successfully submitted I want to redirect to another page in the application.

I have been trying to use **wp_redirect** to do this but all I get is an error reported by the form (it only shows **x parse error** on the page). The code I am having trouble with is this part at the very end (everything else is working fine):-

```
   //redirect after successful form submission
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
```

I have tried different values for the wp_redirect argument even hard coding a URL but I still get the same issue.

Could anyone please give me a pointer to where I am going wrong??

The code is quite large but I thought it better to include it for completeness below:-

```
// Create a custom post and populate custom fields from a standard Elementor form
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {
    
    //make sure its our form
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

     if ( 'Member_Details_Form' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    // iterate all the fields and get them into an array
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }
     
    // assign each field to its own variable - member details
    $address = $fields['member_address'];
    $postcode = $fields ['member_post_code'];
    $contact_number = $fields ['contact_number'];
    $date_of_birth = $fields ['date_of_birth'];

    // assign each field to its own variable - emergency contact details
    $full_name = $fields ['full_name'];
    $relationship = $fields['relationship'];
    $emergency_address = $fields['address'];
    $post_code = $fields['post_code'];
    $telephone_number = $fields['telephone_number'];
    
    // assign each field to its own variable - courses
    $courses = $fields['courses'];
     
    // assign each field to its own variable - sign off box
    $consent_for_marketing = $fields['consent_for_marketing'];
    $date = $fields['date'];
    
    
    //check if a current members_details post exists - only ever want just one
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); //the logged in user's id
        $post_type = 'member_details';
        $posts = count_user_posts( $user_id, $post_type ); //count user's posts
    
    //if no current members_details post exist create a new one
            if( $posts < 1 ){
                //user has no posts so we will create a new one
                
         global $user_ID;
         $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => $name,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author' => $user_ID,
        'post_type' => 'member_details',
        'post_category' => array(0)
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);             
                
        //change the title of the post to the current logged in user
        set_title($post_id);
            }
    
    //make sure we have the latest post_id
    $latest_cpt = get_posts("post_type=member_details&numberposts=1");
    $post_id = $latest_cpt[0]->ID;
 
   //change the title of the post to the current logged in user
    set_title($post_id);

   //populate some custom fields on the custom post from the Elementor form data
    
   // add member address details.
   $field_key = "member_address";// map this to an elementor field
   $value = $address;
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
    
   // add member post code.
   $field_key = "member_post_code";// map this to an elementor field
   $value = $postcode;
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
    
   // add member contact number
   $field_key = "contact_number";// map this to an elementor field
   $value = $contact_number;
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id ); 
    
   // add member date_of_birth
   $field_key = "date_of_birth";// map this to an elementor field
   //$date_of_birth = new DateTime($date_of_birth);
   $value = $date_of_birth;   
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id ); 
    
   // add emergency contact name
   $field_key = "full_name";// map this to an elementor field
   $value = $full_name;
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id ); // map this to an elementor field
    
    // Save a checkbox or select value.
    $field_key = "relationship";
    $value = array($relationship);
    update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
    
   // add emergency contact address details.
   $field_key = "address";// map this to an elementor field
   $value = $emergency_address;
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
    
   // add emergency contact  post code.
   $field_key = "post_code";// map this to an elementor field
   $value = $post_code;
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
    
   // add emergency contact  contact number
   $field_key = "telephone_number";// map this to an elementor field
   $value = $telephone_number;
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id ); 
    
    // add info on courses they are interested in
    $field_key = "courses"; 
    $value = array($courses);
    update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
       
    // add consent for marketing
    $field_key = "consent_for_marketing";
    $value = array($consent_for_marketing);
    update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
       
    // add signature date
    $field_key = "date";// map this to an elementor field
    $value = $date;   
    update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id ); 

    //since a post exists make sure the user role is set to member
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $wp_user_object = new WP_User($current_user->ID);
    $wp_user_object->add_role( 'member' );
       
    //redirect after successful form submission
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit();
    
}, 10, 2 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do it the Elementor way with record and handler.

Below you can find a general code to be used by anybody for an Elementor redirect:

```
//redirect URL to be setup
$redirect_url = '/after-form?encoding='.base64_encode($fields['email']);

//add to record the redirect URL
$redirect_to = $record->replace_setting_shortcodes( $redirect_url );

// Set redirect action to handler
$handler->add_response_data( 'redirect_url', $redirect_to );
```

In the example above the form is redirected with an encoding in the GET parameter.

Comment: I tried it and got the following error message "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add_response_data() on null" .